# Can ScriptLink load a remote file?

Tags: 2013, javascript, scriptlink

When I try to load a remote file through ScriptLink it doesn't work.

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptReg2" language="javascript" name="https://somesite.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/my-script.js" Defer="false" runat="server" Localizable="false"/>-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ScriptLink` always look in `/_LAYOUTS/1033` for the scripts to load. I doubt you can load remote js files with it.

> **Note**: `_LAYOUTS/1033` would be true when the SharePoint language is set to English. For multilingual site we can use `Localizable`
>   property of `ScriptLink`, where you can set it true or false. I believe
>   that false looks for the scripts in the /_layouts folder and true
>   would look at the localization folder

You can choose the traditional `<script>` block to load remote files.

Check out [When to use scriptlink, scriptblock and script](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114323/when-to-use-scriptlink-scriptblock-and-script) and [ScriptLink vs Script tag, what’s the difference?](http://thomasdaly.net/2010/12/16/scriptlink-vs-whats-the-difference/)

Answer (score 0):

No, it Looks only relative to the "_layouts"-Path

Comment: @ leopold - please argument your answer or it will risk being deleted.

Comment: Looks perfectly valid answer to me. ScriptLink is only scoped to local _layouts path, it cannot be used for external sources.

Comment: @C.Marius. There is no Argumentation, it does what it does. The only Argumentation because of lacking documentation is looking at the generated html-tags or decompiling the class where you can find that the Output is built using 
"SPHttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl(str1, localizable), true)" where str1 is the path string given to the control. But the short answer is still: No, it doesn´t because it Looks only for files in layouts. (where the later one is the Argumentation)

Comment: That is exactly what i mean - not arguing on your answer, but on the lack of details on your answer. Please update with your comments, it should be sufficient.